# What's the first column of numbers in a HEX dump of a certain file?

Tags: memory, hexadecimal

For example,

```
00000200  6E 74 3D 22 49 45 3D 65  64 67 65 22 20 2F 3E 0D   nt="IE=edge" />.
00000210  0A 20 20 20 20 3C 6D 65  74 61 20 6E 61 6D 65 3D   .    <meta name=
```

Answer (score 7):

it's the *offset*

In general, your file begins at 0x0000h, and then
it's shown at 16 bytes each time. So the next address
is 0x0010h (that's 16 bytes  = 10h bytes).

In your example, you are showing at 200h bytes from the
begining, and then 210h bytes from the begining... :)

Comment: wouldn't "offset" be the correct term? (offset from start of file, 0 being the start)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the same thing..

Comment: @horatio Perfect, it's "offset" the most common name. I'll edit my answer, when I was typing it I completly forgot the name and used the generic "address"

Comment: @ekaj: not being an expert, I haven't heard "address" used in this respect. One thing I can say though is that "address" implies a qualified location, where "offset" is a relative location. ("123 main street" is an address, "next door" is an offset)

Comment: Why is hexdump showing 16 bytes at a time?

Comment: Also how is 16bytes = 10h bytes

Comment: @briankip :  16 bytes = it's arbitrary. We hardly use the number 10 when we're dealing with binaries and so on, we tend to use 8 or 16, since they are power of 2. And the number 16, when represented in hexadecimal, is written 10 :) In hexadecimal, you have (...)08,09,0a,0b,0c,0d,0e,0f,10,11(..)